# создать страницу в opencart 2.0

Tags: opencart

Помогите создать страницу в опенкарте! Хочу созздать страницу "О нас" создавал и в админке,в статья,задавал ей url затем ссылался на нее но она не анйдета, создавал просто файлы и ссылался на них тоже не находит страницу, как это сделать???

Answer (score 1):

1) Войдите в административную панель OpenCart. Введите в адресной строке вашего браузера `http://yourdomain.com/admin`. Если вы установили Opencart во вложенную папку, к примеру, «store», то вам потребуется ввести `http://yourdomain.com/store/admin`
Введите ваше имя пользователя и пароль.

2) Перейдите в `Catalog` > `Information`

3) Нажмите кнопку `Insert` для создания новой страницы

4) Введите заголовок страницы и вставьте весь необходимый текст в поле `Description`. Вы можете использовать визуальный редактор для форматирования текста, вставки изображений и создания ссылок. Кроме того, вы сможете редактировать HTML код. Для этого нажмите кнопку `Source`.

5) Выберите вкладку `Data`. Тут вы можете определить ключевые слова для страницы, установите порядок сортировки `Sort Order` и включите `enable` или отключите `disable` эту страницу.

6) Сохраните изменения и проверьте как работает ваш сайт. Конкретные страницы отображаются в информационном блоке.

7) Нам нужно получить ссылку на нашу новую страницу для вставки ее в главное меню. Нажмите на ссылку на страницу в информационном блоке и скопируйте ее адрес из адресной строки вашего браузера.

8) Отредактируйте код в файле `header.tpl` для добавления ссылки на страницу в верхнем меню. Файл находится в папке `/catalog/view/theme/themeXXX/template/common.`

9) Отредактируйте файл с помощью PHP редактора. Найдите строки меню. Они должны выглядеть примерно следующим образом:

```
<ul class="links">
        <li class="m1"><a href="<?php echo $home; ?>"><?php echo $text_home; ?><strong></strong></a></li>
        <li class="m2"><a href="<?php echo $wishlist; ?>" id="wishlist-total"><?php echo $text_wishlist; ?><strong></strong></a></li>
        <li class="m3"><a href="<?php echo $account; ?>"><?php echo $text_account; ?><strong></strong></a></li>
        <li class="m4"><a href="<?php echo $shopping_cart; ?>"><?php echo $text_shopcart; ?><strong></strong></a></li>
        <li class="m5 last"><a href="<?php echo $checkout; ?>"><?php echo $text_checkout; ?><strong></strong></a></li>
</ul>
```

Код может отличаться в зависимости от шаблона.

10) Каждая строка кода отвечает за соответствующий geryn меню. Скопируйте последнюю строку кода:

```
<li class="m5 last"><a href="<?php echo $checkout; ?>"><?php echo $text_checkout; ?><strong></strong></a></li>
```

Добавьте новую строку и вставьте туда код, который вы скопировали

11) Класс `last` должен быть присвоен последнему пункту меню. Так как мы добавляем новую страницу последней в меню, то класс `last` должен быть удален из предпоследнего элемента.
Замените следующий код:

```
<?php echo $checkout; ?>
```

на адрес страницы, который мы копировали ранее.
Следующий код

```
<?php echo $text_checkout; ?>
```

должен быть заменен на заголовок элемента меню.

12) Вот полная строка со всеми внесенными изменениями:

```
<li class="m6 last"><a href="http://templatetesting.com/ron/opencart/index.php?route=information/information&information_id=8">Test<strong></strong></a></li>
```

13) Весь блок меню:

```
<ul class="links">

    <li class="m1"><a href="<?php echo $home; ?>"><?php echo $text_home; ?><strong></strong></a></li>
    <li class="m2"><a href="<?php echo $wishlist; ?>" id="wishlist-total"><?php echo $text_wishlist; ?><strong></strong></a></li>
    <li class="m3"><a href="<?php echo $account; ?>"><?php echo $text_account; ?><strong></strong></a></li>
    <li class="m4"><a href="<?php echo $shopping_cart; ?>"><?php echo $text_shopcart; ?><strong></strong></a></li>
    <li class="m5"><a href="<?php echo $checkout; ?>"><?php echo $text_checkout; ?><strong></strong></a></li>
    <li class="m6 last"><a href="http://templatetesting.com/ron/opencart/index.php?route=information/information&information_id=8">Test<strong></strong></a></li>
```

14) Сохраните файл. Теперь страница добавлена в главное меню.

Comment: Спс! мне вставлять не надо было в меню, но я просто понял как должна выглядеть ссылка и вставил ее в другое место !

Comment: Расширенный вариант ответа на случай, если кому в меню нужно будет вставить страницу

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно создать страницу в Каталог/Статьи
задаете ей alias
и обращаетесь к ней
к примеру www.site.com/o-nas/